# Cross workbook Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

Hey guys im trying to perform vlookup through cross-workbook. Im trying to write it this way.. but it seems not working using "x" and "x2"..

```
Folder = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"

Dim OptioneeManWb As Workbook
Dim TransOutWb As Workbook
Dim TransOutWs As Worksheet
Dim TermWb As Workbook
Dim TermWs As Worksheet

Set OptioneeManWb = Workbooks("optionee statement manual.xlsx")
Set TransOutWb = Workbooks.Open(Folder & "employee transfer out.xlsx")
Set x = TransOutWb.Worksheets("out").Range("A:C")
Set TermWb = Workbooks.Open(Folder & "employee terminated listing.xlsx")
Set x2 = TermWb.Worksheets("terminated").Range("A:C")


OptioneeManWb.Sheets("manual optionee stmt").Range("C6:C" & lastrow2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B:B,x,3,0)"
OptioneeManWb.Sheets("manual optionee stmt").Range("D6:D" & lastrow2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B:B,x2,3,0)"
OptioneeManWb.Sheets("manual optionee stmt").Range("C6:C" & lastrow2, "D6:D" & lastrow2).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
OptioneeManWb.Sheets("manual optionee stmt").Range("C:F").Copy
OptioneeManWb.Sheets("manual optionee stmt").Range("C:F").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

TransOutWb.Close
TermWb.Close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` awaits an address of a range as second parameter.

```
.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B:B," & x.Address(External:=True) & ",3,0)"
```

In your case `"=VLOOKUP(B:B,x,3,0)"` the `x` is not recognized as variable because it is within a string. Also you need to fill in the address in here (in external format so that the different workbook gets recognized too). Also see [Range.Address Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-address-property-excel) for info.

Also declare the variables to make sure the are of type range: `Dim x As Range, x2 As Range` at the top of your procedure.

---

```
OptioneeManWb.Sheets("manual optionee stmt").Range("C6:C" & lastrow2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B:B," & x.Address(External:=True) & ",3,0)"
OptioneeManWb.Sheets("manual optionee stmt").Range("D6:D" & lastrow2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B:B," & x2.Address(External:=True) & ",3,0)"
```

Comment: what you mean by address?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` wants an address as second parameter. An address that looks like `[employee transfer out.xlsx]out!$A:$C` you get this address with `x.Address(External:=True)`

Comment: I don't see why this gets voted down? Would be nice of the person who did it to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

First You have to declare the variables x and x2 like this way :

Dim x as range
Dim x2 as range

Comment: As this is a good idea anyway, it is not the answer and does not solve the issue in any case. So I guess this should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: If the variables aren't declared, they will default to `Variant` and then will be given the subtype `Variant/Range` when set to be a reference to a range.  So, although it is good practice to define variables explicitly, it is not related to the OP's problem.